# Java BigDecimal: How to set scale only if it's greater than certain precision point?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I have a use case where I want to set scale only if the number's precision is bigger than certain number.
In other words, I want to set scale to 4 if the precision is 5 but leave the number as it is if precision is less than 4.

This is the expected result I am expecting ->

`123.123` => `123.123` -> leave the number as it is because precision is less than 4.

`123.123456` => `123.1235` -> scale is set, and rounded up.

`123` => `123` -> leave the number as it is, since precision is less than 4.

`0.1234445` => `0.1234` -> scale is set, and rounded down.

How can I achieve this result using Java's BigDecimal?

Comment: have you tried somthing? you can use `ceil` and `round` functions..

Comment: I have tried using setScale method.

Comment: ```
if (value != null) {

            // set the precision only if the value has decimal value. 
            if (value.ulp().compareTo(new BigDecimal(1)) < 0) {
                value = value.setScale(PRECISION_SCALE, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
            }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems like the question you really are asking is "How do I truncate the decimal portion of a BigDecimal so that it has at most 4 numbers to the right of the decimal point?"

First, I think you should ensure you understand what `scale` and `precision` mean with regards to a `BigDecimal`.

If you run this small program:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<BigDecimal> decimals = new LinkedList<>();
    decimals.add( new BigDecimal(".123456"));
    decimals.add( new BigDecimal("1.23456"));
    decimals.add( new BigDecimal("12.3456"));
    decimals.add( new BigDecimal("123.456"));
    decimals.add( new BigDecimal("1234.56"));
    decimals.add( new BigDecimal("12345.6"));
    decimals.add( new BigDecimal("123456"));

    for(BigDecimal bd : decimals){
        System.out.println(bd.toPlainString() + ". scale = " + bd.scale() + ", precision = " + bd.precision());
    }
}
```

You'll see the following output:

```
0.123456. scale = 6, precision = 6 
1.23456. scale = 5, precision = 6
12.3456. scale = 4, precision = 6
123.456. scale = 3, precision = 6
1234.56. scale = 2, precision = 6
12345.6. scale = 1, precision = 6
123456. scale = 0, precision = 6
```

You should now see that what you want to do is query and then adjust the `scale` of the number.

```
static BigDecimal doIt(BigDecimal input){
    if(input.scale() > 4){
        return input.setScale(4, RoundingMode.HALF_DOWN);
    }
    else{
        return input;
    }
}
```

A little test program shows the output is what you requested:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<BigDecimal> decimals = new LinkedList<>();
    decimals.add(new BigDecimal("123.123"));
    decimals.add(new BigDecimal("123.123456"));
    decimals.add(new BigDecimal("123"));
    decimals.add(new BigDecimal("0.1234445"));


    for (BigDecimal bd : decimals) {
        System.out.println(bd.toPlainString() + " ---> " + doIt(bd));
    }
}
```

Output

```
123.123 ---> 123.123
123.123456 ---> 123.1235
123 ---> 123
0.1234445 ---> 0.1234
```

Answer (score 0):

These properties have access methods, you could just test them directly:

```
public static void setScaleIfNeeded(BigDecimal bd, int scale, int minPrecision) {
    if (bd.precision() >= minPrecision) {
        bd.setScale(scale);
    }
}
```

Comment: `bd.precision()` does not give correct results. e.g. for `123.123`, `bd.precision()` results in `6`.

Comment: @pratiksanglikar - It gives the correct results.  You are defining "precision" to mean something different than the authors of BigDecimal did.